# Get the List of all events from Calendar iphone in sorted order

Tags: ios, events, calendar

I want to get the events of this month or selected month but I want to get these in sorted order(by date). so it is possible to get in sorted order? I am using below code to get the events. Its returns the events but not in the sorted order.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:currentStart endDate:currentFinish calendars:nil];
        [eventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate
                                          usingBlock:^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop) {

                                              if (event) {
                                                  [eventsDict setObject:event forKey:event.eventIdentifier];
                                                 // NSLog(@"event.eventIdentifier %@",event.eventIdentifier);
                                              }

                                          }];
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation ([Calendar and Reminders Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html)), there is a specific note about this: **Retrieving events from the Calendar database does not necessarily return events in chronological order**.

The solution is to use a built-in selector `compareStartDateWithEvent:` that can be used to sort an array of events. Therefore, the code could be changed to:

```
NSMutableArray *eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[eventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate
     usingBlock:^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop) {
         if (event) {
             [eventsArray addObject:event];
         }
     }];
NSArray *sortedEvents = [eventsArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareStartDateWithEvent:)];
```

This method results in a sorted array of events, not a dictionary of events as shown in your example.